# 'strcmp' char array in C

Tags: c

```
...
main() {
   char **src_ip[10];
   char **dest_ip[10];
   char **lat[10];
   char *ip[20];

   while{
      //Read file
      //fgets();

      src_ip[j] = &data[0];
      dest_ip[j] = &data[1];
      lat[j] = &data[2];

      int idx;
      int addip;

      for(idx=0; idx<20; idx++)
      {
          addip = 0;
          //Check to see if the IP address is already in the array.
          if ((strcmp(*(src_ip[j]),  ip[idx]) == 0) ||
              (strcmp(*(dest_ip[j]), ip[idx]) == 0))
          {
              addip=1;
              break;
          }
          //If the IP address was already found then addip would equal 1.
          if (!addip){
              printf("new node: %s",*(ip[idx]));
          }
          else
              printf("Exist");
      }
   }
   j++;
}
```

I want to compare char string in two 1d array - array `src_ip[j]` and `dest_ip[j]` - and insert into one array ip[idx]. For example, when I look for `ip[1]`, it will go to `src_ip[1]`, meaning that it's only referring to one array - `ip[idx]` - instead of looking separately into `src_ip` and `dest_ip`.

There must be a problem in the code - maybe I left something out?

Comment: `while(idx);` at the end of the for loop looks terribly wrong. Also: what is data[] ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if((strcmp(*(src_ip[j],ip[idx]) == 0) && (strcmp(*(dest_ip[j]),ip[idx]) == 0))
                     ^^
```

You can't have both `*(src_ip[j])` and `*(dest_ip[j])` equal to `ip[idx]`. What you meant to use was the `||` operator instead of `&&`. (By the way, there's a missing `)` where I marked above)

Also your `while(idx)` doesn't make sense. Are you controlling the loop with the `for` above, or the `while` below? If with the `while`, then you'll get an infinite loop if the condition is true since you are never changing it inside the loop.

Comment: And an equal number of `(` and `)`...

Comment: @BoPersson, yeah there's one missing!